# Qt i18n: QT_TR_NOOP in c++ qstr() in qml

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization

I already consider myself with enough knowleadge in the i18n for Qt, but I came across a very interesting case, that im not even sure it can be done.

This is situation:

I have a class Station.cpp, that translates a string (before I was using tr(), but I switch to QT_TR_NOOP). This string is afterwards exposed to qml, and display as a normal text.

```
forecast_titles.append(QT_TR_NOOP("Tonight"));
```

The problem comes when after exposing that variable to qml, it was sucessfully translated when the text was generated (when the Station.cpp code was run), but when I change the language, the variable does not reevaluate in qml, and remains displaying in the original language.

Why I use QT_TR_NOOP:

> **QT_TR_NOOP ( sourceText ):** Marks the string literal sourceText for dynamic translation in the
>   current context (class), i.e the stored sourceText will not be
>   altered.

So, i thought that, when it arrives to qml, and display it as

```
qsTr(mainboard.forecast_titles[0].title) + langProperty.emptyString
```

it should make the translation.

I guess the problem comes from the definition of QT_TR_NOOP, where it specifies ***in the current context class***

Is it possible to do it some other way? (I'm talking about QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(), or any other command) It could be that is really not possible, and I can find a solution, but still would like to know if is feasible.

**Remarks**: Just assume that the variable in cpp is suscessfully exposed to QML,there is not the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `QT_TR_NOOP` in your QML code, thus letting the upper layer translate the string?

Comment: Exactly that is my back up solution. The only "drawback" for that approach is that I need to pass from c++ to qml lets say a code, and transform that code to the specific string. Thanks any way for your idea!

Comment: I don't get you, that shouldn't be your backup solution, indeed it is the intended way to do that in QML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I suggest to use `QT_TR_NOOP` directly in your QML code, thus letting the upper layer translate the string.

Note that [Qt Quick applications use the same underlying localization system as Qt C++ applications](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html). So, maybe it's worth to use it in the right place as mentioned by the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about translation context. Use `qsTranslate('Station', mainboard.forecast_titles[0].title) + langProperty.emptyString` on the QML side.